# How can I handle mal-encoded character with Python 2?

Tags: python, unicode, internationalization, shift-jis

The HTML file I am fetching has some characters that are not supported by the encoding specified in HTML header:

I found the following ones are not supported by Shift_JIS encoding but actually used. My browser can correctly show those characters.

- ∑  n-ary summation U+2211
- ﾟ   halfwidth katakana semi-voiced sound mark   U+FF9F
- Д  cyrillic capital letter de  U+414

When I try to read this HTML file and decode for processing, I get UnicodeDecodeError.

```
url = 'http://matsucon.net/material/dic/kao09.html'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
response.read().decode('shift_jis_2004')
```

Any good way to process the HTML that has mal-encoded characters without getting an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
response.read().decode('shift_jis_2004',errors='ignore')
```